# Best Approach to get `ResultSet` size

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

What's the best approach (Speed) to get `RestultSet` size in Java, so I can store them in `Array`, which I need to specify it's size before creation, I've found the following:

1. Call `ResultSet.last()`, then call `ResultSet.getRow()`.
2. Iterate through `ResultSet` using `next()` while having a counter.
3. Execute a `SELECT COUNT` query for any given query.
4. Execute `FOUND_ROWS()` after each query.
5. Read results into `ArrayList` then converting it to Array.

Comment: Why not read the data into a list, then copy that into an array?  Sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @Vihar I did some search about it, but I'm trying to see opinions about which one would considered better than other. that's why I have listed all possible solutions.

Comment: @skaffman it's listed as option #5, but is considered good practice, to do that, meaning, wouldn't take time in CPU convert that `ArrayList` into `Array`?

Comment: @mabuzer Of course it'll take CPU time, everything does. That's what CPUs are for. It's going to be orders of magnitude faster than querying the database though, don't you think?

Comment: @skaffman when I said take CPU, I meant than other options, I know at some levels it depends on amount of data returned from query, but from my understanding, Is it going to be faster than calling `ResultSet.last()` which going to move cursor to last record? or it's better than handling things at database layer?

Comment: @mabuzer Practically any method you call on the `ResultSet` is liable to perform a network operation, and that particular one is liable to make it impossible to retrieve anything but the last row. All of this completely obliterates your micro-performance concerns. The correct approach to this problem is to forget about the array altogether and store the results in a linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option would be #5: put the data in an `ArrayList` and use `toArray` to extract an array.

Options #3 and #4 (extra queries) are a bad idea, speed-wise, because database queries have an inherent latency, no matter how fast your database is.

Options #1 and #2 are just a bad idea; `ResultSet` is meant to be iterated in one direction. While you *can* move the cursor in other directions, most JDBC drivers will not perform too well doing this.

Finally, you should *really* reconsider returning an array. Java arrays are great for creating new collection data types and high-performant libraries, but for most business purposes they are inferior to the standard Collections API.